# How to implement a rating and review system for WordPress custom posts?

Tags: php, comments, rating, review

I want to have a  rating and review system for custom post type.

This is the method i am thinking of 
->Create a custom post type 
->Create meta fields
->Create a form to post reviews front end.

But how can i link the custom post type page and review together?

---

Another method i am thinking of is to tweak comments . But all the reviews will get added up in the WordPress comment menu in backend

Looking to best method to rating and review system. 
Thanks

Comment: What are the fields of review?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż hi .. fields i am looking to add are rating,review field,name & email

Comment: so it’s almost the same as comments. I would go with tweaking comments, I guess...

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż but how can i separate the reviews from getting added up WordPress comment menu?  i dont think that that there is a feature to add custom comment type . If there is please let me know

Comment: And what sort of separation would be enough? Display with different color? Hide them at all?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Is it possible to hide? any documentation links please. But not sure if that will be an effective method because the moderation will become difficult in this case. May be different color and tag like "review" will be good solution i think.